# Debugging AI Tie Logic in NegaMax Algorithm for Tic Tac Toe in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js, tic-tac-toe, minimax

**Question:**

I'm currently working on a Tic Tac Toe game using the minimax algorithm in p5.js, and I've encountered an issue with the AI's behavior. Despite my efforts, I can't seem to get the AI to work correctly. I've included a link to my p5.js code on the p5.js editor for reference: **[Link to the p5.js code](https://editor.p5js.org/vklizardman06/sketches/3Z-15xwF9)**.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```js
function AI() {
  let bestMove = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let bestScore = -Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < GRIDSIZE; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < GRIDSIZE; j++) {
      if (isMoveValid(i, j)) {
        makeMove(i, j);
        let score = NegaMax(false);
        undoMove(i, j);

        if (score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = score;
          bestMove = { x: i, y: j };
        }
      }
    }
  }
  makeMove(bestMove.x, bestMove.y);
}

function NegaMax(isMax) {
  if (IsGameOver()) return 10;
  let bestScore = -Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < GRIDSIZE; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < GRIDSIZE; j++) {
      if (isMoveValid(i, j)) {
        makeMove(i, j);
        let score = -NegaMax(!isMax);
        undoMove(i, j);
        bestScore = max(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
  }
  return bestScore;
}
```

I've thoroughly reviewed the code, I think the problem. Is when a tie occurs in the search it would rather lose then win.

I've been working on debugging the AI logic for my Tic Tac Toe game in p5.js using the NegaMax algorithm. To fix the issue, I've tried the following:

1. **Reviewing My Code:** I carefully reviewed my code to ensure that the implementation of the minimax algorithm and the game logic were correctly implemented according to the algorithm's principles.
2. **Comparing with others code:** I've looked at other Tic Tac Toe implementations using NegaMax in p5.js to compare my code and identify any bugs.
3. **Whiteboarding:** I've used a whiteboard to visually map out the game's state, AI decision-making process, and potential outcomes to verify that the algorithm's logic aligns with my expectations.

Despite this, I'm still having issues with the AI's behavior. Specifically, I expected the AI to make optimal moves based on the minimax algorithm, but it sometimes makes unexpected or invalid moves.

I am seeking to identify the problem in my code or logic that's causing this issue.

Comment: What's the `depth` parameter for? You decrement it when you recurse, but you never use it for anything.

Comment: Hello Barmar, I was going to use it however I realized it isn't necessary in my case I forgot to remove it entirely. I can say with confidence this is not the issue.

Comment: Did you notice that the logic in `AI()` is the same as `MiniMax(isMax = true)`? You probably don't need both functions.

Comment: Hello Barmar, I have consolidated the code into one function called Negamax. However the logic in the bot is relevant for it to work. Also I removed my solution because it worked to a certain point after refreshing the page however it is still beatable. I think the problem might be when the bot finds a tie however I am not sure why. I have edited the question to include the new code